# Javascript Regex For only numbers and no white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I was very surprised that I didn't find this already on the internet.
is there's a regular expression that validates only digits in a string including those starting with 0 and not white spaces

here's the example I'm using

```
  function ValidateNumber() {

  var regExp = new RegExp("/^\d+$/");
  var strNumber = "010099914934";
  var isValid = regExp.test(strNumber);
  return isValid;
}
```

but still the isValid value is set to false

Comment: Can you show a example of the content you want to test? Just `/^\d+$/` should work...

Comment: share what you tried so far?

Comment: `^\d+$`..I am also surprised that you didn't make an attempt to write this regex

Comment: @Scarnet, added a detail to my answer that you missed. The string should be double escaped like this `"^\\d+$"`

Comment: It **is** on the Internet. It's in any page describing regular expressions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `/^\d+$/`.

That means:

- `^` string start
- `\d+` a digit, once or more times
- `$` string end

This way you force the match to only numbers from start to end of that string.

**Example here:** https://regex101.com/r/jP4sN1/1
**jsFiddle here:** https://jsfiddle.net/gvqzknwk/

---

## Note:

If you are using the *RegExp* constructor you need to double escape the `\` in the `\d` selector, so your string passed to the *RegExp* constructor must be `"^\\d+$"`.

---

So your function could be:

```
function ValidateNumber(strNumber) {
    var regExp = new RegExp("^\\d+$");
    var isValid = regExp.test(strNumber); // or just: /^\d+$/.test(strNumber);
    return isValid;
}
```